# If a theorem is named after Mike, is it a "Mike Theorem" or "Mike's Theorem"?

Tags: mathematics, language

While learning mathematics, I found "Hilbert spaces", "Vieta's Formulas", and "Cauchy Equation." My question is what is the rule for using "Mike's Theorem" and "Mike Theorem"?

Why are there not "Hilbert's spaces", "Vieta Formulas" and "Cauchy's Equation"?

---

Re-EDIT: I think @Kimball is right.

> Since this is already a older question with answers, I'd suggest removing your edit and asking a separate question.

And please forget about the following EDIT.

---

EDIT: The "-ian"s hit on me. There are the words like "Newtonian", "Hamiltonian", "Jacobian" and "Abelian". So, when is something called a "Mike-ian Something", or simply a "Mike-ian"? Like a "Pfaffian" and a "Wronskian"?

Comment: You won't find rules. You'll find human conversations. Person 1: "My proof is done except for one step where I'm stuck." Person 2: "Oh, you can just use [this theorem over here]". Person 1: "Who proved **that**?" Person 2: "Schlobotnick." Person 1 several days later, in a lecture: "We apply Schlobotnick's Theorem to conclude..."

Comment: There is "Cauchy's equation" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_equation

Comment: Watch out for "Stoke's Theorem" (wrong ... they guy

Comment: Usually the person's surname is used, so it would be very odd to have either a "Mike Theorem" or a "Mike's Theorem".

Comment: There is no "usual". For one of many counter-examples, see: "Delaunay triangulation" and not "Delaunay's triangulation".

Comment: If it's a theorem about Mike themself, it's definitely a Mike Theorem. Otherwise there isn't a standard. (This is, or used to be, controversial territory with diseases in medicine. Some argue (including me) it should be Alzheimer Disease rather than Alzheimer's Disease, because unlike Lou Gehrig's (ALS), it isn't so named because Alzheimer *had* the disease; nor did he create the disease, so he can't exactly "own" it.)

Comment: Since this is already a older question with answers, I'd suggest removing your edit and asking a separate question.

Comment: @Kimball You are right, and I'll reedit it.

Answer (score 15):

In theory (see below) it would be the possessive only if the person that developed the theory on their own also, possibly, named it after themself. While Hilbert, for example, was an early developer of the concept, the name *Hilbert Space* was applied to it by von Neumann. And, Hilbert wasn't the only early explorer of this world. Perhaps that last is the key. The name is in some sense an honorific due to the work of a great mathematician.

On the other hand, *Fermat's Last Theorem* was clearly Fermat's work and his alone, though I don't know the history of applying the name.

So, if Mike alone develops a theory and names it, then it is Mike's Theorem but if Mary names it after Mike and she and Mike developed it, then she would (in theory, again) name it the Mike Theorem.

However, in theory, Theory is the same as Practice, but not in practice. So, don't expect consistency.

An anecdote in math is that Hilbert had to ask someone else, possibly von Neumann, but I don't remember: "What is this Hilbert Space thing, anyway?"

Comment: I think Hilbert Space doesn't describe a specific mathematical space, but a set of spaces that all share a specific property, so I think they are Hilbert spaces rather than Hilbert's space, which would imply a specific space?  So perhaps it is possessives that are appropriate for singular specific things (like algorithms).

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, one can, of course, describe something as _a Hilbert Space_, using the general reference with a singular form.

Comment: but it would be awkward to say "**a** Hilbert's space" (because "Hilbert's space" implies a specific entity).  The Higgs boson, which is a specific thing would perhaps be a clearer example of your criterion (which sounds reasonable to me).

Comment: "Fermat's Last Theorem was clearly Fermat's work and his alone" — Well, the problem statement was due to Fermat, but proving it and thus making it a theorem was most definitely not.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial We do say, for example, "**a** Green's function."

Comment: @d_b yes (+1), and it does sound awkward to me, perhaps it wouldn't if I were used to it.  As I mention in my answer English is very irregular and I suspect a lot of it depends on whether it sound right to the community that coins the usage.  There are a variety of things that might cause it to sound awkward, one of which is whether it refers to some specific thing rather than a class of things.

Comment: "In theory (see below)" Where does this theory come from? Absent a source, it sounds more like someone's idiosyncratic take on how they would like things to be named.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with what Buffy and Dikran say, but I also think one can be more precise about typical usages.

- [possessive usage] Use when a theorem etc is due to someone.  It need not indicate uniquely defined result. E.g. [Cauchy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_inequality) or [Wedderburn's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_theorem) can refer to multiple results, determined by context. It is also bit awkward to use the possessive form if there multiple names--who says Taniyama-Shimura(-Weil)'s conjecture?
- [adjectival usage] Usually only used if it specifies a relatively well-established and unique result etc.  Also preferred if there are multiple names, e.g., the [Cauchy-Schwartz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) or the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture.  If needed, another adjective can be added to ensure unique specification, e.g., "the Big Picard Theorem." (Don't say "the Picard theorem", but "Picard's theorem" is okay in context.)

That said, sometimes it is just author/speaker preference, and may depend on the surrounding grammar or minor nuances.  E.g., sometimes I'll write "Langlands' Conjectures", and sometimes "the Langlands Conjectures", though at least for me there is a bit of sense when I use the latter that I am referring to a *specific* and *precise* set of conjectures.

Answer (score 5):

There probably isn't a single reason, and I certainly don't disagree with Buffy's (+1), but I think part of it may be whether it describes a single thing or a set of things.  "Hilbert space" doesn't describe a single space, it is a set of mathematical spaces that have a common property:

> [A Hilbert space is a real or complex inner product space that is also a complete metric space with respect to the distance function induced by the inner product.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)

If we were to write "Hilbert's space" it would imply a specific space, rather than a set of different spaces, so it would be awkward to write "a Hilbert's space".  We could say "a Thompson's gazelle", but in that case we are treating "Thomson's gazelle" as specifying a specific species (and the differences between particular examples are irrelevant).

Unfortunately English is very irregular and I suspect a lot of it is down to whether something "sounds" right when you say it (and as a result it evolves substantially over time).  A lot of students these days say "based off" rather than "based on", which sounds awkward to me (a generational thing?).  I can see the logic of "based off" as it generally means something that departs from its base concept.  Which is right?  These days, both are "right" because both are in common usage.

Comment: Well, we do say "a Green's function" and sometimes it is relevant to discuss and contrast multiple Green's functions. As you say, it's all quite irregular.

Comment: @Anyon yes "a Green's function" sounds awkward to me, but I expect I'd get used to it if I used them.  I'm glad it is "Hilbert space" ;o)

Answer (score 4):

Great insights in the other answers.  I just thought I'd mention an ancillary thing that is worth bearing in mind: According to [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy), Mike's theorem may actually have been discovered by John.

Comment: In the context of math, this is sometimes called the [Arnold principle](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~wxm/Arnold.htm), which of course was formulated by Berry: "If a notion bears a personal name, then this name is not the name of the discoverer." The associated Berry principle states "The Arnold Principle is applicable to itself."

Answer (score -3):

It's always "Someone Something" if *named after* someone (it's THE (Mike) thing), until you *reference* someone (it's HIS (Mike's) thing). "Naming after" is basically inheriting the name, not denoting ownership (something of someone). Simply put, if someone names his child after Mike, then it's Mike child, not Mike's child. But it's just semantics, maths have much more mundane crap, search pi vs tau for example if interested.